# Dynamic checkboxes - Error: Collection is read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm quite new to MVC4 and my past experience with asp.net has been working with Webforms, so I think I need some careful hand holding. Thank you in advance!

I'm creating a simple web application that is similar to choosing lotto numbers. At the moment the user chooses whichever numbers they want (no limit, starting with "1") and posts it to the next page where I continue to do something with the numbers the user has chosen. The number of numbers - to choose from is dynamic and represented by checkboxes.

The problem is that when the view is submitted, I get the error page "Collection is read-only."

Model - LottoNumbers.cs
bool[] numbers is to store which numbers the user has checked.

```
namespace Lotto.Models
{
    public class LottoNumbers
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool[] numbers { get; set; }

        public LottoNumbers() {
            numbers = new bool[49];
        }

        public LottoNumbers(int limit)
        {
            numbers = new bool[limit];
        }
    }
}
```

in the HomeController.cs ...
I declared LottoNumbers ln, and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Lotto.Models;

namespace Lotto.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public LottoNumbers ln;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SetNumbers()
        {
            ln = new LottoNumbers(30); 
            // 30 checkboxes will be generated on the view

            return View(ln);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult SetNumbers(LottoNumbers l)
        {
            // get checkbox values
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View - SetNumbers.cshtml

```
@model Lotto.Models.LottoNumbers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SetNumbers";
}
<h2>SetNumbers</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.name)
    </div>

    <div id="numberlist">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.numbers.Length; i++)
    {
    <div class="item-number" style="">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.numbers[i])
        <label class="lbl-number" for="numbers[@i]">@(i+1)</label>
    </div>
    }
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset everything" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your array to a list.

```
  public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Numbers { get; set; }

    public LottoNumbers()
    {
        Numbers = new List<bool>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Numbers.Add(false);
        }
    }

    public LottoNumbers(int limit)
    {
        Numbers = new List<bool>();
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i ++)
        {
            Numbers.Add(false);
        }
    }
```

then your **view** would be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>

    <div id="numberlist">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="item-number" style="">
                @Html.CheckBox("Numbers[" + i.ToString() + "]")
                <label class="lbl-number" for="numbers[@(i + 1)]">@(i + 1)</label>

            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset everything" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

}
```

**Null Reference Exception**

You are most likely getting the null reference exception after submitting because you are not passing a model back to the view. You set up your page to expect a LottoNumbers model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SetNumbers(LottoNumbers l)
{
    // get checkbox values
    return View(); //Nothing being passed to the view
}
```

so after post when your code gets to here

```
@foreach (var numberBool in Model.Numbers)
```

it blows up as the Model is null. You can fix this in several ways depending on how you want your app to run. If you want the user to see a blank list of numbers after submit simply do this and add some sort of success message on post back

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SetNumbers(LottoNumbers l)
{
    //process stuff
    ln = new LottoNumbers(30);
    return View(ln);
}
```

you can also simply redirect the user back to the index page. Either way the error is caused because you are not passing in a model with numbers back to the view.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time as I needed a refresher on using Lists. Thank you!

Comment: Oddly I'm getting a NullReferenceException on the @foreach line *after* submitting the page. I don't understand...

Comment: added a "Null Reference Exception" section that explains why you are getting a Null Reference Exception

Comment: Ah no wonder. I was getting ahead of myself. Thanks for your patience! Now is another issue... I got back the variable Name entered on the view, but the list shows all false values even though I checked some of the boxes.

Comment: Fixed my problem - I changed the foreach in view to a for loop and use @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Numbers[index])

Comment: I updated the view to solve your problem. The reason this was happening : MVC binds by the name of an html object. With collections it binds by doing 
Name[0], name[1], ect.

Comment: Yes the editor for works as well :) Glad you solved it

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the stack trace of your "Collection is read only" error, you can see that it's happening during Model Binding, which is when it tried to recreate your LottoNumbers object from the data passed back from the form post.

You're getting the error because you're initialising your object with an array size using you're constructor that takes a parameter, but when it posts back the data, it doesn't know what size the array needs to be when it recreates the object.

To solve this, it would be better to use a List instead, and have the size as a property of your LottoNumbers object.

Using a List means you don't have to pre-initialise the array with a size. And having the size as a property means you can embed the size in a hidden input variable, so that it can be passed back to the controller, and it should correctly do the model binding.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I'll use a list then. I would vote up this if I had enough rep. ^^;

Comment: I was too slow with my answer, but I will vote up for you. :)

Comment: @PaulBinder: I'll up vote you as well because I was about to add an example, but you beat me to it... Team work!